# While installing MySQL-python using pip am ending up with the following output and unable to install MySQLdb

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, mysql-python

```
  _mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No
 such file or directory
  error: command '"C:\Users\mahendra.gaur\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsof
t\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

and then the following code is shown in red color

```
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:
\users\\mahend~1.gau\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-zxhadg\\MySQL-python\\set
p.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r
n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\mahend~1.gau\appdata\l
cal\temp\pip-x_l2nw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-manag
d --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\mahend~1.gau\appdata\local\te
p\pip-build-zxhadg\MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are unable to compile the package on Windows, you can install the precompiled binary:

```
http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysql-python
```

Simply download the `.whl` file and install by using

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win32.whl
```

or

```
pip install MySQL_python-1.2.5-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl
```

depending on your system architecture.